# foreach datatable in list 'GetEnumerator' error

Tags: c#, asp.net

Im getting this error on the second foreach loop, the logic seems fine to me.. :

(foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'datatable' because 'datatable' does not contain a public instance definition for 'GetEnumerator')

```
foreach (DataTable testdatatable in test)
                    {
                        foreach (DataRow datarow in testdatatable)
                        {
                            string value = datarow.Field<string>("Slave_IO_Running");   //Looks for "Slave_IO_Running" status.

                            if (value == "Yes")
                            {
                                results.Add(siteName + ": WORKING"); //adds working to the visual table 
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                results.Add(siteName + ": REPLICATION ERROR"); //adds not working to the result list
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Iterate DataTable.Rows Property:

```
 foreach (DataRow datarow in testdatatable.Rows)
```